# Finding A Transforation Matrix under an Isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am making my way through my textbook in preparation for an exam and I was wondering if anyone could assist with this problem. This problem is probably easy for most of you here, but I have been starting at it for 2 hours with absolutely no head way made - at all.

Recall, $M_{2\times 2}\left ( \mathbb{R} \right )$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ as real vector spaces. Now, consider the explicit isomorphism $T$ induces by $e_{1} \mapsto e_{1,1}, e_{2} \mapsto e_{2,1}, e_{3} \mapsto e_{1,2}, e_{4} \mapsto e_{2,2}$

Now define a linear map $L_{A}$ from $M_{2\times 2}\left ( \mathbb{R} \right )$ to itself by taking $A,B\in M_{2\times 2}\left ( \mathbb{R} \right )$ and setting

$L_{A}=AB$

Under the isomorphism T, $L_{A}$ becomes a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{4}$, thus, $L_{A}$ is represented by an element of $\mathbb{R}^{4}$.

A) Find the matrix of $L_{A}$ under this isomorphism, with respect to the standard basis and show your answer is correct.

B) Find an explicit form for all matrices in $M_{4\times 4}\left ( \mathbb{R} \right )$ that commute with the image of every $L_{A}$ under $T$ and show that the set of all matrices is also isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ as a real vector space.

I may be struggling partially because I do not understand what is meant by $e_{1,1}$, $e_{1,2}$ etc. I know we are talking about standard bases, but I have never seen them represented with commas and the book makes no indication what this notation means. Further, as far as the problem goes, I have no clue where to start. I understand about the relationship between matrices and transformations, I just do not understand where to begin this problem. If someone could walk be through it, or provide useful hints, that would be great.

Comment: $e_{1,1}$ is the basis matrix element with a 1 in the upper left component (i.e, row 1, column 1) and a 0 everywhere else.   In general, $e_{n,m}$ refers to a matrix with a 1 in row n, column m and 0 elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

suppose you write the matrix $X=\left( \begin{array}{cc} x & y \\ z & w \end{array} \right)$ as a vector $X'=(x,y,z,w)^T$. then if $A$ is the matrix $\left( \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array} \right)$ the product $AX$ is written as the vector 
$$
(ax+bz, ay+bw, cx+dz, cy+dw)^T
$$
this transformation of $X \to AX$ is accomplished as a direct operation on the **vector** representation of $X$ by the matrix operation:
$$
 L_AX'=\left( \begin{array}{cccc} a & 0 & b & 0 \\ 0 & a & 0 & b \\ c & 0 & d & 0 \\0 & c & 0 & d \end{array} \right) \left( \begin{array}{c}x \\ y \\ z \\ w \end{array} \right)
$$